# testing shiny modules with additional variables

Tags: r, testing, shiny, module

I've been playing with shiny modules and finally got some bits and pieces working. However, I've been totally thrown by an issue testing individual modules.

What I usually do is turn each module into a small app to test how it works. This particular module takes additional variables, but I don't seem to be able to insert some test vars into the test app as I would usually. Unfortunately, this fails.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

Many thanks

```
histogram_ui <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))
  )
}

histogram_server <- function(id, var, bin) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[var()]])
    #debug
    observeEvent(var(), {
      print(var())
    })

    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = bin(), main = var())
    })
  })
}

#testing----
ui_t <- fluidPage(
  histogram_ui("test")
)

server_t <- function(input, output, session) {
  histogram_server("test", var = "mpg", bin = 10)
}

options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE) #ctrl+F3 to bring up
shinyApp(ui_t, server_t)
```

Comment: Try passing reactive variables to the modules.

Comment: How and where would I go about doing that? Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
histogram_ui <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))
  )
}

histogram_server <- function(id, var, bin) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
 
    observeEvent(c(var(), bin()), {
      print(var())
    })
    
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(mtcars[[var()]], breaks = bin(), main = var())
    })
  })
}

#testing----
ui_t <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("myvar","Choose",choices = colnames(mtcars)),
  sliderInput("bins","Number of Bins", min=1, max=10, value=5),
  histogram_ui("test")
)

server_t <- function(input, output, session) {
  histogram_server("test", var = reactive(input$myvar), bin = reactive(input$bins))
}

options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE) #ctrl+F3 to bring up
shinyApp(ui_t, server_t)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd not understood that I'd need to build a fully fledged mini app. Thanks again